# Paper image correction

Tags: c#, emgucv

Suppose I have this image: 
[image: source]

How to automatically detect the outher box And Correct the corners of the destination image based on that outher box, so that the image looks like this?

Can somebody answer with C# code to do this task?

[image: result]

Comment: "Can somebody answer with C# code to do this task?" hopefully not. Ad rem: long, thick lines can be easily detected with `Hough transform`.

Comment: I think that the answer is about 25 lines of code. But I don´t know how to do.

Comment: @Omaha, I am able to detect the outer box perfectly if it is Rotated. But if it has perspective, then the detected Box is different shape than real box.

Comment: I will not do your homework... Show us what you tried, what is working, what is not and then we'll be talking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is Automatic perspective correction for quadrilateral objects

This was answered here
http://answers.opencv.org/question/20717/paper-image-correction/?answer=20727#post-id-20727

Comment: Please note - if that link breaks, this answer loses all value. Can you summarize at least the vital parts that someone reading this answer should know?